# Spring MVC 3 url beginner

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have written the following code :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class Home {

@RequestMapping(value = "index")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "welcome")
public String welcome(@RequestParam("txtname") String name, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("msg", name);
    return "index";
}

}
```

Now I have two doubts. I want something like /test to load index() directly. Now I have to type /test/index. How do I configure that.

Secondly index() and welcome() is almost same. Just that the request parameter is added to the output. I wrote index() because /welcome won't work if there is no parameter. I want txtname to be made optional or something as such so that welcome can be dropped.

Comment: You could try to set the @RequestParam to required=false: @RequestParam(value = "txtname", required = false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want something like /test to load index() directly. Now I have to type /test/index.

Just skip the extra mapping:

```
@RequestMapping
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

---

> I want txtname to be made optional or something as such so that welcome can be dropped.

Try this:

```
@RequestParam(value = "txtname", required = false)
```

Besides your `welcome()` method can be simplified:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "welcome")
public String welcome(@RequestParam("txtname") String name) {
    return new ModelAndView("index", "msg", name);
}
```